# QGIS renders map output as tiles

Tags: qgis

When I export my map, it looks like the picture below. I kind of understand where it comes from as the map is from a web server and loaded as tiles (AHN4), but how do I fix this? It doesn't show like this in the normal map viewer.

[image: map output]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What type of service is it (WMS, XYZ, WCS etc), can you provide a link?

Comment: This is the link;

https://ahn.arcgisonline.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Hoogtebestand/AHN4_DTM_50cm/ImageServer